# ExecuteNonQuery results in "Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I am using VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

```
protected void btnsave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAAD-CH-HP;Initial Catalog=ovms;Integrated Security=True;");
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO request(reqtype, source,employeeID, vehID, destination) VALUES ('" 
    + official + "','" + source + "','" + emp_id + "','" + DropDownList1 + "','" + destination + "')");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

As I run the program this exception occurs

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: Welcome to the site Saad, please format your code and detail what steps you have already tried to solve this.

Comment: I tried to revive the Patient...

Comment: That's not a very good title for a question ...

Comment: Why don't people start out using parametrized queries?

Comment: dear sir ChaosPandion can you please write a code for parameterized query so that this exception can be handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update you code to this below. Set the SQLCommand's connection property.

```
protected void btnsave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAAD-CH-HP;Initial Catalog=ovms;Integrated Security=True;");
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO request(reqtype, source,employeeID, vehID, destination) VALUES ('" + official + "','" + source + "','" + emp_id + "'," + DropDownList1.Text + ",'" + destination + "')");
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

or in the construction after you SQL Test, add myConnection

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO request(reqtype, source,employeeID, vehID, destination) VALUES ('" + official + "','" + source + "','" + emp_id + "'," + DropDownList1.Text + ",'" + destination + "')",myConnection);
```

Comment: dear sir the code you recommend are not working

Comment: what exception are you getting? still the same one as before?

Comment: sir the error in browser is:

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.

Comment: Source Error:


Line 36:            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 37:         myConnection.Close();
Line 38:     }
Line 39: }


Source File: c:\Users\Saad-CH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite5\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 38

Comment: Please change the DropDownList1 value in the SQL String to DropDownList1.Text if the control you are using is a text box or change it to DropDownList1.SelectedValue if your DropDownList control is a DropDownList control.

Comment: and the exception in vs is
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.

Comment: Please see what I've changed in the code above. I am now removing the apostrophe (') before and after the DropDownList1.Text

Comment: dear sir i understand that please write the code to to eliminate the ExecuteNonQuery exception like i have a user name and user id in db and 2 text feilds and a save button

Comment: like this one
  protected void btnsave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAAD-CH-HP;Initial Catalog=ovms;Integrated Security=True");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO crudchk
                         (emp_name, emp_1d)
VALUES        ('"+emp_name+"','"+emp_id+"')",myConnection);
           
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }

Comment: dear sir i also have tried this code

Comment: protected void btnsave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAAD-CH-HP;Initial Catalog=ovms;Integrated Security=True");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = myConnection;
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO crudchk (emp_name, emp_1d)
VALUES (?,?);");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", emp_id.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_name", emp_name.Text);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  myConnection.Close(); i also try this code

Comment: thanks alot sir DeNNDeV thats because of you i have done that i'll send you the code i tried if you want to see that i hope you will always their for me thank u thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not associated the command with the connection.

You need to add another parameter to your `SqlCommand` constructor, with the connection handle.

Comment: sir kindly make that parameter of sqlcommand